# How to Rename Attachments from outlook msg (.msg files) with the msg file name it self (string before .msg) with Python

Tags: python, outlook, attachment, file-rename, msg

I have a folder that has nearly 12k (.msg) files each has a csv attachment.
I managed to get a code to extract the attachment from each .msg file. but due to attachment and subjects are similar the attachment keeps getting over written! I tried to rename with msg.subject but the subject of the msg is similar

```
import win32com.client
import os
inputFolder = r'directory with my msg' ## Change here the input folder
outputFolder = r'directiry for attachments' ## Change here the attachments output folder

for file in os.listdir(inputFolder):
    if file.endswith(".msg"):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        filePath = inputFolder  + '\\' + file
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(filePath)
        att = msg.Attachments
        for i in att:
            i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputFolder, str(msg.subject + ".csv")))
#Saves the file with the attachment name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find an algorithm which allows identifying attachments uniquely - try to combine the attachment file name with email data such as [ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) and etc.

Don't forget to exclude forbidden symbols from the result file name before trying to save the attachment.